# Fill a variable in a condition from xml

Tags: powershell

what I have is a variable called $usercity.city obtained with a Msoluser query to get a user city.
What I need to do is to populate a variable called $icthead depending from that value. I mean I have like 30 cities with differents icthead, is there a way different from a simple switch to do that?
Like loading from an external XML or stuff like that... thanks! If you think a simple switch won't slow down my script I'm gonna go that way.

A pratic example of what I want to do is:

```
$usercity=Milan then $icthead=email1@company.it
$usercity=London then $icthead=email2@company.it
$usercity=chicago then $icthead=email3@company.it
```

but for 20 or more cities. A solution would be loading every email on an array[$usercity] but I can't do it by myself cause I'm really bad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A switch will not be slow at all. But you should give an example of what you want to do or what you have tried so far.

Comment: @marsze added an example

Comment: If it's always that simple you could do `$icthead = $usercity + "@email.it"`. Otherwise it depends on where the email addresses come from.

Comment: @marsze it was an example, it obviously isn't that easy... otherwise I wouldn't have asked for a xml solution.

Comment: If your example doesn't cover YOUR specific use case, it's worthless.

Comment: @marsze edited once again, sorry I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something like this is what you are looking for, but if you have the data in an excel sheet with the e-mail for each city in a row of data, then you can grab the e-mail of that city this way:

```
foreach($city in $usercity.city)
{

icthead

function icthead {

# This part is to open up the designated xlsx file and make powershell "look" in it.
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$DestinationPath = "Your xlsx file location"
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($DestinationPath)
$Sheet = $workbook.worksheets.item("Name of the excel tab your information is in")
$Sheet.activate()

# This will find the horizontal row that the city is in. 
$GetCity = $Sheet.Range("Vertical range .ex B2:B9999").find("$City")
$Row = $GetCity.Row

# This will require you to download the ImportExcel module - https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/3.0.0 - All credit to Douglas Finke
$XL = Import-Excel "Your xlsx file location"

# .Mail is an example. Should be your column title. It will grab the value that is in that row under that column and save it in the variable. Remember that xlsx is 0 indexed. 
$CityMail = $XL[$row].Mail 

}    

$IctHead = $CityMail
Write-host $IctHead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an `external reference`. It can be done by **many ways**. Here is some of those:

**Hashtable/Dictionary variable:**

```
#declare hashtable type variable.
$ht = @{}
#populate it with key/value items.
$ht.Add('Milan','email1@company.it')
$ht.Add('London','email2@company.it')
$ht.Add('Chicago','email3@company.it')
#input city name Milan
$city = 'Milan'
#now call hashtable variable by its key Milan
$ht[$city]
#output
email1@company.it
#usage example
Set-UserProperty -City $city -Email $ht[$city]
```

**XML string:**

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
       <City name="Milan">
          <Email>email1@company.it</Email>
       </City>
       <City name="London">
          <Email>email2@company.it</Email>
       </City>
       <City name="Chicago">
          <Email>email3@company.it</Email>
       </City>       
</Dictionary>
"@
$xml.Dictionary.City | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $city} | Select -ExpandProperty Email
```

**CSV string:**

```
$city = 'Milan'

$CSV = @"
"City","Email"
"Milan","email1@company.it"
"London","email2@company.it"
"Chicago","email3@company.it"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

($CSV | Where-Object {$_.City -eq $city}).Email

#output
email1@company.it
```

**XML/CSV files:**

1. Create either a XML or a CSV file with the same content as those of the respective `here string` (`@" ... "@`). E.g:

*myfile.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
       <City name="Milan">
          <Email>email1@company.it</Email>
       </City>
       <City name="London">
          <Email>email2@company.it</Email>
       </City>
       <City name="Chicago">
          <Email>email3@company.it</Email>
       </City>       
</Dictionary>
```

*myfile.csv:*

```
"City","Email"
"Milan","email1@company.it"
"London","email2@company.it"
"Chicago","email3@company.it"
```

2. Replace the `here string` (`@" ... "@`) in the code above with `Get-Content -Raw -Path 'myfile.xml'` or `Get-Content -Raw -Path 'myfile.csv'`, respectively. E.g:

   > [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Raw -Path 'myfile.xml'
   >
   > or
   >
   > $CSV = Get-Content -Raw -Path 'myfile.csv'
3. The rest of the code stays the same.